# How to fix a broken gsettings setting without gnome-session?

Tags: gnome, dconf, gsettings

Using Gnome on 16.04 I slipped up on the command line and killed Gnome. It now won't start - just goes back to gdm!

How can I restore the setting?

I've tried using gsettings from the command line on a TTY but it complains that it can't connect.

I got into my desktop again by moving the `.config/dconf/user` file out of the way, but now I've lost all my config.

FYI the command that broke my desktop (don't try this at home, kids!) was:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor': <0>}"
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Get back to a working desktop

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in.

```
mv .config/dconf/user{,-old}
exit
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> back to the gdm login screen and log in. All your settings are gone, but at least you're back to your desktop.

### 2. Dump your old settings

Start a Terminal.

```
echo "user-db:user-old" >db_profile
DCONF_PROFILE=~/db_profile dconf dump / >old_settings
```

Now edit `old_settings` with your favourite editor and remove/correct the bit you broke.

## 3. Import your corrected old settings.

```
rm db_profile
mv .config/dconf/user-old ~/user-settings-delete-later
dconf load / <old_settings
```

Things should be Ok now and you can delete your `~/user-settings-delete-later` file if happy.

Credit due here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199864/23542